# useSWRMutation post request optimisticData gives me a type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, post, types, swr

i have a POST request using SWR:

```
  const { trigger, data, error, isMutating } = useSWRMutation(`${baseUrl}radios`, sendRequest);


  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormData> = data => {
    trigger(data, {
      rollbackOnError: true,
      optimisticData: current => ({ ...current, data }),
    });
  };
```

*optimistiData* gets red underlined on my IDE with the following problem:

> (property) optimisticData?: Response | ((currentData?: Response | undefined) => Response) | undefined
> Type '(current: Response | undefined) => { data: FormData; headers?: Headers | undefined; ok?: boolean | undefined; redirected?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; ... 10 more ...; text?: (() => Promise<...>) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Response | ((currentData?: Response | undefined) => Response) | undefined'.
> Type '(current: Response | undefined) => { data: FormData; headers?: Headers | undefined; ok?: boolean | undefined; redirected?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; ... 10 more ...; text?: (() => Promise<...>) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '(currentData?: Response | undefined) => Response'.
> Call signature return types '{ data: FormData; headers?: Headers | undefined; ok?: boolean | undefined; redirected?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; statusText?: string | undefined; ... 9 more ...; text?: (() => Promise<...>) | undefined; }' and 'Response' are incompatible.
> The types of 'headers' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'Headers | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.ts(2322)

i don't understand which headers it's referring to